# Codeigniter routes don't work correctly

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I have two string in routing config.

```
$route['education/course/(:any)'] = "education/course/$1";

$route['education/course/(:any)/(:num)'] = "education/lection/$1/$2";
```

But when I went to `/education/course/my_course/1`, the first rule worked, but the second didn't.

Please help! I'm newbie in CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes run in the order they are defined. Your second one will never be applied because the (:any) wildcard is capturing, well, anything.

I believe you should be able to switch the order so the most specific is first, followed by the least specific:

```
$route['education/course/(:any)/(:num)'] = "education/lection/$1/$2";
$route['education/course/(:any)'] = "education/course/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both two routes are similar in the first three segments

```
education / course / (:any)
```

And since Route.php runs procedural (line by line),

Requesting a page like `/education/course/my_course/1` matches the first route pattern (below)

```
$route['education/course/(:any)'] = "education/course/$1";
```

And also, requesting a page like `/education/course/my_course/1/23` will still matches the first route pattrn, because Route.php only cares if your requested URL link matched the specified route pattern or not, otherwise go check the next route.

So, switching the order of the routes will fix the problem.